# Scrollbar for single item in listview in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, scrollbar

I am making simple application in Android.

The application contains a custom listview. This listview contains only a single item. Now I want make this single item scrollable on the entire screen of the phone.

How can I achieve this so that my single item can rotate from top to bottom or bottom to top on the screen?

Below is the code for my custom adapter for the listview.

```
private class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private int id;
    private List <String>items ;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context,List<String> list )
    {
        super(context,R.layout.main, list);
        mContext = context;
        //id = textViewResourceId;
        items = list ;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.devicelist, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(items.get(position));
        // Change the icon for Windows and iPhone

        text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        if(items.get(position) != null )
        {
            text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            text.setText(items.get(position));
          //  text.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
          //  int color = Color.argb( 200, 255, 64, 64 );
          //  text.setBackgroundColor( color );

        }
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you have a single item, don't use listView, use ScrollView

Comment: but i will go add more item as i found search of near by device through bluetooth. if i press on bluetooth device name and drag to bottom of screen then it should go to bottom of screen. i don't know how can i do it this feature ?

Comment: i think you want a drag layer in which each row is dragable.

Comment: hi, but how that drag layer works ? can u show me some link or example so i can see and if it is same what i need i can implement in my application.